# Do you need to use __name__=__main__ statement for running any script in python?

Tags: python

I just wanted to understand why you have to use `if __name__ == '__main__':` if we can run any python script even without using that statement.
For example, I can run this script without using it:

```
def hello():
      print("hello")
      return 1234

# And here is the function being used
print(hello())
```

Comment: Well, it's not why you *have to* use that statement, it's why you might *want to*.

Comment: You usually never want side effects from importing a module, like having it run a bunch of operations on you.

Answer (score 5):

It's done so that code is only executed when run as a script and not when you import the module.

Answer (score 0):

Code in the global namespace runs slightly slower. It's easy to make a `main()` function, so why not do it? It is optional though if you don't mind the module "running" when you import it